# I can't display variables of different types included in array

Tags: c++

I have to do a program for college.

I have 3 classes already declared in the statement of the problem.
First class:

```
class piesa_a{
    protected:        
        int id;
        char *tip;
        int pret;
};
```

Second class:

```
class piesa_b:public piesa_a
{    
    private:
        float lungime;
        bool bw;
};
```

Third class:

```
class piesa_c:public piesa_a
{    
    private:
        int nr;
        piesa_b *buf;
};
```

In main I need to create an array in which to store items such piesa_a, piesa_b, piesa_c. Then I have to sort items by price.

**I have this code so far:** http://pastebin.com/nx2FGSfe

The program is incomplete because it does not displays each item in the array.

I got stuck here. But if you display the array's elements when they are outside of it, it works.

**SHORT:** I have an error on line 143 and I want to solve it.

```
main.cpp:143:18: error: request for member ‘afisare’ in ‘*(v + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)i) * 4u)))’, which is of non-class type ‘piesa_a*’
```

The code is here:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class piesa_a{     
    protected:       
        int id;
        char *tip;
        int pret;

    public:
        piesa_a()
        {
            id = 0;
            tip = new char[1];
            pret = 0;
        }

        piesa_a(int aidi, char *typ, int pretz)
        {     
            id = aidi;
            tip = new char[strlen(typ)+1];
            strcpy(tip,typ);
            pret = pretz;     
        }

        piesa_a&operator =(piesa_a alta)
        {
            id = alta.id;
            tip = new char[strlen(alta.tip)+1];
            strcpy(tip,alta.tip);
            pret = alta.pret;

            return *this;
        }

        virtual void afisare()
        {
            cout<<"\n Piesa A: "<<id<<" "<<tip<<" "<<pret;
        }     
};

class piesa_b:public piesa_a
{

private:
    float lungime;
    bool bw;
public:
    piesa_b():piesa_a(){lungime = 0;bw = 0;}
    piesa_b(float lg,bool bl, int aid, char *tipi, int pretzz):piesa_a(aid,tipi,pretzz)
    {
        lungime = lg;
        bw = bl;
    }
    piesa_b&operator =(piesa_b &c)
    {
        id = c.id;
        tip = new char[strlen(c.tip)+1];
        strcpy(tip,c.tip);
        pret = c.pret;
        lungime = c.lungime;
        bw = c.bw;

        return *this;
    }

    void afisare()
    {
        piesa_a::afisare();
        cout<<"impreuna cu piesa B: "<<lungime<<" "<<bw<<"\n";
    }

};

class piesa_c:public piesa_a
{     
    private:
        int nr;
        piesa_b *buf;
    public:
        piesa_c():piesa_a(){nr=0; buf = new piesa_b[nr];}
        piesa_c(int n, piesa_b *bu,int aid, char *tipi, int pretzz):piesa_a(aid,tipi,pretzz)
        {
            nr = n;
            buf = new piesa_b[nr];
            for(int i=0;i<nr;i++)
                buf[i]= bu[i];
        }

        piesa_c&operator =(piesa_c &alta)
        {       
            id = alta.id;
            tip = new char[strlen(alta.tip)+1];
            strcpy(tip,alta.tip);
            pret = alta.pret;
            nr = alta.nr;
            for(int i=0;i<alta.nr;i++)
                buf[i] = alta.buf[i];           
        }

        void afisare()
        {                       
            for(int i=0;i<nr;i++)
                buf[i].afisare();           
        }       
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {       
    piesa_b *H;
    H = new piesa_b[2];

    piesa_a A(4,"TIPA",120);
    piesa_b B(100,1,3,"TIPA",120);
    H[0]=B;
    H[1]=B;
    piesa_c C(2, H,14,"TIPC",20);

    piesa_a** v = new piesa_a*[3];

    v[0] = &A;
    v[1] = &B;
    v[2] = &C;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        v[i].afisare();

    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I dont understand the question. Where are you stuck? what do you want to do? there is memory leak in your program.

Comment: I have an error at line 143: main.cpp:143:18: error: request for member ‘afisare’ in ‘*(v + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)i) * 4u)))’, which is of non-class type ‘piesa_a*’. I want to solve it.

Comment: Please paste the code into the question.

Comment: `v[i]` in is a pointer in the erroneous line. You cannot use the dot operator on a pointer, you need to say `v[i]->afisare();`. That's what your error message is trying to tell you, in somewhat terse language.

Comment: Write your comment as a answer and i'll accept it, if you want...

Comment: @Bart My mistake, didn't realize it was being phased out

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (and current C), casts are almost always a sign that the programmer didn't know how to use the language as it is supposed to be used. If you need an array of 3 types of data, the cleanest solution is an array of objects of a class that is base to the 3. And if you want to display each item differently, you'll want to overload the `<<` operator, so you just iterate over the array and go `<<` on each item. Sorted by price means that the class includes a price field, and you use the sort from the standard template library, passing a comparison operation that just compares prices.